# Remove Global Search from selected pages of Customer Service Experience Template

Tags: experience-cloud, global-search

I have an Experience site for Guest users that uses the OOTB `Customer Service template`

The site has the usual suspects of pages:

- Home
- Contact Support

I added a new Page `DataCollect` that includes a Screen Flow that I deep link to in outbound emails. On this new page, I do not want the Search box to appear. How do I make this Search box disappear?

There are a variety of answers/posts like this [blog](https://simplysalesforce.com/2016/02/24/til-how-to-hide-the-global-search-bar-on-the-standard-community-builder-header/) suggesting I use CSS selectors and `display:none` but this might have been true in 2015, but surely can't be true now.

I also read about developing custom themes (see [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout)) but this looks way too complicated for this simple requirement.

is there a point-and-click config solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward, you just have to know where to look

This [help article provides the solution](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_theme_apply.htm&type=5)

In Builder ..

- `Settings | Theme | Configure`

  - `New Theme Layout` call it `Default wo Search` and associate it to the `Customer Service Template`
  - Click the `Gear` icon next the the template name for your new theme layout
  - Check the box `Hide the header region and navigation` (you don't have the option to change the picklist value for `Search Component` to `None`)

[image]

- Going back to Builder, choose the page you want to not have the Search Box and

  - click `... Page Actions | Page Settings | Properties`, then
  - check `Override the default theme layout for this page` and assign the `Default wo Search` theme you created in the previous step.

[image]

*Of course this is a pretty blunt instrument as it removes all elements of the header from the template, including any custom navigation you have but for the OOTB Customer Service template, an effective technique*

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to cropredy's answer a way to make it less blunt is to create an essentially empty Aura component which implements "forceCommunity:searchInterface". This will make the component available for selection in the Experience site builder and since it's empty it will essentially be hiding the search bar.

So instead of checking "Hide the header region and navigation" leave it unchecked and choose your empty Aura component as the Search Component from the drop-down menu below. Everyting else is as cropredy explained.

Empty component example:

```
<aura:component description="EmptyECSearchComponent" implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface"> 
</aura:component>
```